# WPF - What to do when a Dependency Property is another Control in the XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, dependency-properties, behavior

I'm hoping this will be my last question today. I'm in a hurry and google is not helping much (that or I'm searching the wrong places).

I created some custom properties and behaviors so my RadioButtons can alter my labels Content and the mask of my TextBoxes.

I could pass a String as a property, but how do I pass another control as a property? (AdjustedLabel is of type Label)

```
    <RadioButton i:CPF_CNPJAdjustBehavior.LabelContent="Apple" i:CPF_CNPJAdjustBehavior.AdjustedLabel="??????????" Content="CPF" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,216,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="a" IsChecked="True">         
        <int:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <i:CPF_CNPJAdjustBehavior/>
        </int:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </RadioButton>
    <Label Content="Label" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,81,0,0" Name="MyLabel" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

What do I have do write in "?????????" to set AdjustedLabel to the label named "MyLabel" ?

Thanks in Advance

Clark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AdjustedLabel="{Binding ElementName=MyLabel}"` will do what you're searching for.

Consider reading some documentation for getting started with WPF, Bindings, Dependency Properties and XAML syntax. You could start with [XAML Syntax In Detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723.aspx), [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) and [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! It's so simple i'm quite embarassed. Worked like a charm